# Completion with respect to stronger norm is no subset?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $M$ be a normed vector space equipped with two norms $\| \cdot \|_1$ and $\| \cdot \|_2$, where $\| \cdot \|_1$ is stronger than $\| \cdot \|_2$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\forall x \in M: \| x \|_2 \leq c \|x\|_1
\end{equation}
Let now $\bar{M}_i$ denote the completion (cp. Reed Simon, Thm. I.3) of $M$ with respect to $\| \cdot \|_i$.

Now I wanted to show, that $\bar{M}_1 \subset \bar{M}_2$ holds.

But somehow, the proof does not work. Therefore recall, how the completion works:

The completion of $M$ w.r.t. $\| \cdot \|_i$ is defined as the set $B_i$ of all sequences that are Cauchy in $M$ w.r.t. $\| \cdot \|_i$ modulo the equivalence relation:
\begin{equation}
(x_n) \sim_i (y_n) \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \| x_n - y_n \|_i = 0
\end{equation}
I.e. $\bar{M}_i = B_i /\sim_i$.

We now have $B_1 \subset B_2$, since $\| \cdot \|_2$ is weaker than $\| \cdot \|_1$. Let $i: B_1 \hookrightarrow B_2$ be the corresponding injective embedding. Now $i$ does descend to an injective map $j: B_1 / \sim_1 \hookrightarrow B_2 / \sim_2$ if and only if $\forall (x_n), (y_n) \in B_1: (x_n) \sim_1 (y_n) \Leftrightarrow i( (x_n)) \sim_2 i((y_n))$ ($\Rightarrow$ is needed for the existence and $\Leftarrow$ for injectivity).

But since $\| \cdot \|_2$ is weaker than $\| \cdot \|_1$, $ \Leftarrow$ does not hold in general. Hence in general $\bar M_1 \subset \bar M_2$ does not hold.

This seems for me quite strange, especially, since the closure of a dense subspace in a complete space is a completion, and here the assertion holds (i.e.: Let X be a normed space, which is complete w.r.t. $\| \cdot \|_i$ and $\| \cdot \|_1$ is stronger than $\| \cdot \|_2$. Let $Y \subset X$. Then the closure of Y in X w.r.t. $\| \cdot \|_2$ contains the closure of Y in X w.r.t. $\| \cdot \|_1$). What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

You are not missing anything. What you want to prove is just not true in general.

Here is a somewhat different perspective of what you want to show: The identity map $\iota : M_1 \to M_2 \subset \overline{M_2}$ is clearly a well-defined bounded linear map. Thus, it is not hard to see that there is a unique continuous extension $\overline{\iota} : \overline{M_1} \to \overline{M_2}$ of $\iota$. What you are asking is essentially whether $\overline{\iota}$ is always injective.

This is not so: To see this, consider the set $M := C^1([0,1])$, with $\|\bullet\|_2 = \|\bullet\|_\sup$ and $\|f\|_1 := \|f\|_2 + |f'(0)|$. Now, fix some $g \in C^1([0,\infty))$ with $g'(0) = 1$ and such that $g,g'$ are bounded. Set $g_n (x) := n^{-1} \cdot g(nx)$. We then have $\|g_n\|_{L^\infty([0,1])} \to 0$ (by boundedness of $g$), but $g_n'(x) = g'(nx)$, so that $|g_n'(0)| = 1$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$. Therefore,
$$
\| g_n - g_m \|_1 = \|g_n - g_m\|_{L^\infty([0,1])} + |g_n'(0) - g_m'(0)| \leq \|g_n\|_{L^\infty} + \|g_m\|_{L^\infty} \to 0,
$$
so that $(g_n)_n$ is Cauchy with respect to both norms. By completeness of $\overline{M_i}$, we thus see $g_n \to g$ with respect to $\|\bullet\|_1$, and it is easy to see $g_n \to 0$ with respect to $\|\bullet\|_2$. Since we have $\|g_n\|_1 \geq |g_n'(0)| = 1$, we see $\|g\|_1 \geq 1$, i.e., $g \neq 0$. But $\overline{\iota}(g) = \overline{\iota}(\lim_n g_n) = \lim_n \iota(g_n) = \lim_n g_n = 0$, so that $\overline{\iota}$ is not injective.

The usual way to ensure that $\iota$ is injective is to already know that $\overline{M_i} \hookrightarrow X$ for a suitable Hausdorff space $X$ (typically, $X$ could be the space of measurable functions with convergence in measure, or the space of distributions, etc.). Note that **one needs to know this for the completion to hold, not just for the spaces $M_i$ themselves**. Indeed, in the above example, we have $M_i \hookrightarrow C([0,1])$, but this was not enough to conclude the injectivity of $\overline{\iota}$.

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph. Apart from that, good example!

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn: What I am trying to indicate there is a possible argument for showing (under additional assumptions) that $\overline{M_1} \subset \overline{M_2}$. Let us assume that there is some Hausdorff space $X$ for which you can show $\overline{M_i} \hookrightarrow X$ for $i = 1,2$. Then let $x,y \in \overline{M_1}$ with $\overline{\iota}(x) = \overline{\iota}(y)$.

Comment: There are sequences $(x_n)_n, (y_n)_n \subset M_1$ with $x_n \to x$, $y_n \to y$, with convergence in $\overline{M_1}$ and hence in $X$. By continuity of $\iota$, also $x_n = \iota(x_n) \to \overline{\iota}(x)$ and $y_n = \iota(y_n) \to \overline{\iota}(y)$, with convergence in $\overline{M_2}$ and hence in $X$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, limits are unique, so that $\overline{\iota} (x) = \lim_n x_n = x$ and $y = \lim_n y_n = \overline{\iota} (y) = \overline{\iota} (x) = x$, which proves injectivity of $\overline{\iota}$. Essentially, this argument shows that $\overline{\iota}$ is the identity.