# maximality of maximal tensor product

Tags: operator-theory, tensor-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^*$-algebras and let $\alpha$ be any $C^*$-norm on the algebraic tensor product $A⊙B$. Why is $A⊗_{\alpha}B$ is the subalgeba of $A\otimes_{max} B$?

In many reference books,they mentioned that there was a natural surjective * homomorphism from  $A\otimes_{max} B$ to $A⊗_{\alpha}B$ ,which reveals that $A⊗_{\alpha}B$ is the subalgeba of $A\otimes_{max} B$.

According to the definition,$A\otimes_{max} B$ denote the  $||.||_{max}$,  $A⊗_{\alpha}B$ is the completion of $A⊙B$ with respect to $\alpha$,$||.||_{max}$ is the maximal $C^*$-norm,I prove that $A\otimes_{max} B$ is the subalgebra of $A⊗_{\alpha}B$(refer to [Completion with respect to stronger norm is no subset?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2694935/completion-with-respect-to-stronger-norm-is-no-subset)) .
Can anyone point out my mistake?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It isn't. The existence of a $*$-epimorphism $\phi:A\to B$ does **not** tell you that $B$ can be seen as a subalgebra of $A$; only as quotient, which is most often not a subalgebra.

To see an easy example, let $A=C_0(\mathbb R)$, $B=\mathbb C$. Then you have for instance the $*$-epimorphism $\phi:A\to B$ given by $\phi(f)=f(0)$, but no subalgebra of $C_0(\mathbb R)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$.

Comment: There was a natural surjective * homomorphism from $A\otimes_{max} B$ to  $A⊗_{\alpha}B$,can we deduce that $A\otimes_{max} B$ is larger than $A⊗_{\alpha}B$?

Comment: You would have to tell me what "larger" means.

Comment: I mean $ A\otimes_\gamma B$ is the subset of $A\otimes_{max} B$? I prove that $A\otimes_{max} B$ is the subset of $ A\otimes_\gamma B$ above,Can you point out my mistake?Thanks!

Comment: I cannot point a mistake because I see no proof. But it is just not true, as the answer to [the question you quoted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2694935/completion-with-respect-to-stronger-norm-is-no-subset) shows. A Cauchy sequence for $\|\cdot\|_\alpha$ needs not be Cauchy for $\|\cdot\|_\max$.

Comment: My proof:For any $x\in A\otimes_{max} B$,there is an sequence $\{x_n\}$in $A \otimes B$ such that $||x_n-x||_{max}\rightarrow 0$ .Since $||.||_{max}$ is the maximal $C^*$ norm ,we have $||x_n-x||_{\alpha}\rightarrow 0$,then $x\in A\otimes_\alpha B=\overline{A \otimes B}^{||.||_{\alpha}}$

Comment: That's very sloppy. You are taking $x\in A\otimes_\max B$, so $x$ is in the completion of $A\odot B$ with respect to the $\|\cdot\|_\max$ norm. Next you say that $x\in A\otimes_\alpha B$; why? At most, what you can say is that any Cauchy sequence in $A\odot B$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_\max$ is also Cauchy with respect to $\|\cdot\|_\alpha$. That's precisely the fact that the identity map is contractive $(A\odot B,\|\cdot\|_\max)\to(A\odot B,\|\cdot\|_\alpha$, whichs allows one to extend it to the closure to get a $*$-epimorphism; that is, a quotient map.

Comment: $||.||_{max}$ is the maximal $C^*$ norm,we have we $||x_n-x||_{\alpha}\leq||x_n-x||_{max}$,$||x_n-x||_{max}\rightarrow 0$ Can we have $||x_n-x||_{\alpha}\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: In an algebra where both $\|\cdot\|_\alpha$ and $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ are defined, yes.

Comment: Iam a little puzzled about the concept of completion.would you mind telling me the exact definition.If Y is the completion of X,is it true Y containg X?THANKS

Comment: Of course, that's the point of a [completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space#Completion).