# Elementary tensors of tensor product of C*algebras

Tags: operator-theory, tensor-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

When $\alpha$ is a $C^*$-norm on $A \times B$, we denote the $C^*$ completion of $A \otimes B$ with respect to $\alpha$ by $A\otimes_{\alpha}B$. I feel a little confused about the elementary tensors of $A\otimes_{\alpha}B$. They have the form $a\otimes b, \ a\in A, \ b\in B$. But the completion of $M$ should be the equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences in $M$.

Comment: What is $M$ ? You mean $M = A \otimes B$ ? Furthermore, what do you ask for ?

Comment: yes，I mean $M=A \otimes B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that in the completion $\tilde X$ of a metric space $X$, the space $X$ isometrically embeds into $\tilde X$ via constant sequences (or more appropriately, the equivalence class containing a constant sequence):

$$X\ni x\mapsto[(x,x,x,\ldots)]\in\tilde X.$$

More often than not, we ignore regarding elements of $x$ as (equivalence classes of) sequences in $\tilde X$, and identify an element of $x\in X$ with this corresponding element in $\tilde X$.

So when considering a completion $A\otimes_\alpha B$, you will more frequently see people refer to $A\otimes B$ as being "inside" of $A\otimes_\alpha B$, rather than be completely formal and consider an isometric embedding of $A\otimes B$ into $A\otimes_\alpha B$.

The elementary tensors of $A\otimes_\alpha B$ are really the images of elementary tensors of $A\otimes B$ under this isometric embedding.  You don't get more elementary tensors in the completion.

Comment: There is a univerality property:If $\phi:A\otimes B\rightarrow C$ is a $*$ homomorphism,then there exists a unique $*$ homomorphism $A\otimes_{max}B \rightarrow C$ which extends $\phi$       If there exist two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ converge( in  maximal $C^*$ norm )to $x\in A\otimes_{max} B$,how to ensure that $lim\phi(x_n)=lim\phi(y_n)$?

Comment: Unless you've misquoted, this is just continuity of a $*$-homomorphism: if $\lim x_n=x=\lim y_n$, then $\lim \phi(x_n)=\phi(x)=\lim \phi(y_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is what you are asking, but 
$$
A\otimes B=\left\{\sum_j a_j\otimes b_j:\ a_j\in A,\ b_j\in B\right\}.
$$
As you say, the completion can be seen as the set of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences in $A\otimes B$.

Comment: Yes,I know how to express the elements of the algebraic tensor product,but what is the element of spatial tensor product of C* algebras ,say $A\otimes_{min}B$ look like.By the definition,it should be the equivalence classes of cauchy sequences in $A\otimes B$.In many reference books,many authors define a * homomophism $\pi :A\otimes _{min}B\rightarrow B(H)$ as $\pi(a\otimes b)T=$...,but $a\otimes b,a\in A,b\in B$ is not the whole $A\otimes_{min} B$.

Comment: You want  $\pi $ to be linear, so the extension to  $A\otimes B $ is automatic. And if it's linear and bounded, it extends to the closure.

Comment: You mean completion of $A\otimes B$ is the closure of $A\otimes B$?But the precise definition of completion of $A\otimes B$ should be the equivalence classes of cauchy sequence.I rememer that I asked you a similar question,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2772010/maximality-of-maximal-tensor-product.I want to want compare $A\otimes_{max}B$ with $A\otimes_{\alpha}B$,where $\alpha$ is any C* norm.I wrote"if $x\in A\otimes_{max}B$,then $\|x_n-x\|_{max}\to 0$.You said it was sloppy.

Comment: No, it was sloppy trying to compare elements completions with respect to different norms. If we take your interpretation of "a completion of a completion", we have to deduce for instance that real numbers and $p$-adic numbers are the same, since both are completions of $\mathbb Q$. And if you mean that I wrote "closure" instead of "completion", once you fix a completion $\overline{X}$, you have that $\overline{X}$ is the closure of $X$.

Comment: If we view $A\otimes_{max}B$as the closure of $A\otimes B$ ,then if $x\in A\otimes_{max}B$, we have 
 $\|x_n-x\|_{max} \to 0$ (by definion of closure,is that true?)   Because any other $C^*$ norm $\alpha$ is less than maximal $C*$ norm.So if $\|x_n-x\|_{max}\to 0$,then $\|x_n-x\|_{\alpha} \to 0$.I don't undersatnd the example you take(under what norm).Can the norm(in your example) be comparable?

Comment: Pro Argerami,I met with some troubles with the elementary tensor products.There is a universal property of algebraic tensor product :For any vector space $Z$ and any bilinear map $\sigma:X \times Y \rightarrow Z$,there exists a unique linear map $\bar{\sigma}:X\odot Y\rightarrow Z$ such that the diagram commutes(i.e.$\bar{\sigma}(x\otimes y)=\sigma ((x,y))$).If $x\otimes y=a\otimes b$,where $a\neq x,b\neq y$,how one can ensure the map is well defined?